# What's the meaning of sensor_msgs/PointCloud2

Tags: pcl, sensor-msgs, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently, I'm using VLP-16 to get  point cloud data. But I am really confused about the structure of sensor_msgs/PointCloud2. I used the commend $ rostopic echo /velodyne_points to check the data. I have known that 32 numbers are used to describe a point. But how to transform these numbers to x, y, z coordinate of the points ? Thanks.

For example:
164, 129, 148, 191,  79,  29,   4, 191, 114, 146, 181, 188, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 63,  7, 0, 0, 0, 70, 88, 8, 112, 61, 127, 0, 0,
163, 248, 106, 191,  20,   9, 209, 190, 228, 208, 137,  62, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   0, 64, 15, 0, 0, 0, 70, 88, 8, 112, 61, 127, 0, 0,
226, 211, 151, 191, 178, 208,   6, 191,  65, 147, 185,  60, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 176, 66,  8, 0, 0, 0, 70, 88, 8, 112, 61, 127, 0, 0,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241136/what%27s-the-meaning-of-sensor_msgs/pointcloud2/) by [iROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/27682/iros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [z1huo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35608/z1huo/) on 2018-08-18**:
I am facing the same problem, could you tell me how that structure works? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PointCloud2 message is defined here: http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html

For interacting with PointClouds it's common to use the PCL datatype: http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros You can subscribe and publish directly as a PCL datatype using `pcl_ros/point_cloud.h`

There are also a couple of iterators defined in sensor_msgs to allow access to the PointCloud2 message without the added dependency on pcl: http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/annotated.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/27682/iros/) on 2016-08-10**:
Thanks a lot. And I have solved this problem now.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-08-11**:
Please click the checkmark buttom at left to indicate your question is solved.

**Comment by [MohamedEhab](https://answers.ros.org/users/40591/mohamedehab/) on 2019-04-16**:
Can you please tell me what solution did you use??